# How to upload image onImageUpload callback in flutter_enhanced_editor in flutter

Tags: flutter

How do we upload a file in the onImageUpload callback, it accepts a paramater of FileUpload type which does not includes the path of the image, so how can we make a dio request to upload the file using MultipartFile

```
HtmlEditor(
  callbacks: Callbacks(
     onImgageUpload: (FileUpload file){
        FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
          "image": await MultipaerFile.fromFile(
             imagePath,
             fileName: 'imagePaht-test',
           )
        })
        Dio.post(
            'url', data:data,
        )
     }
  )
)
```

The problem is imagePath is not accessible from the FileUpload type

Comment: Post the code that you already wrote, and you can find better help that way. People can't guess your setup or boilerplate, you might be asking the wrong question to your problem. Stack Overflow isn't a code request service.

Comment: I guess you would use either `MultipartFile.fromBytes` or `MultipartFile.fromString` depending of what package your `FileUpload` and `HtmlEditor` come from.

Comment: i tried but the method readAsBytes is not available for FileUpload type